# Howto trigger multiple alerts in a realtime bar?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, alerts

I have an indicator that check if the previous 2 candle bars are the same (not the current/realtime bar). The maximum and minumum price value is calculated from their respective high and low values. A buy or sell alert is then triggered when the realtime bar crossover these points.  This part works fine.

My problem is that it only happens once.  If there is a sudden spike in the realtime bar (that crossover the setpoints - which can be multiple times) no further alerts are generated.

This is my code:

```
// This source code is PRIVATE
// © WaxBill2k 2204053

//@version=5
indicator("BarAlerts", overlay = true, max_labels_count = 500)

// INITIATIONS =================================================================

// Initialize boolean for plotshape series
var bool buy = false
var bool sell = false

// Initialize first Buy and Sell levels
var float buy_level = 0
var float sell_level = 0

// Initialize 2Bars
bool upBar = false
bool dnBar = false
bool twoUpBars = false
bool twoDnBars = false

// CALCULATOR ==================================================================

// Find 2Bars
upBar := barstate.isconfirmed and open < close
dnBar := barstate.isconfirmed and open > close

// Set 2Bars
twoUpBars := upBar and upBar[1]
twoDnBars := dnBar and dnBar[1]

// Calc bars
if twoUpBars or twoDnBars
    buy_level := math.max(high[1], high)
    sell_level := math.min(low[1], low)

// CONDITIONS ==================================================================

// goto SELL
if low < sell_level[1]
    buy := false
    sell := true
// goto BUY
else if high > buy_level[1]
    buy := true
    sell := false

// DISPLAY =====================================================================

// Buy and Sell points ---------------------------------------------------------

lblb = label.new(x = bar_index, y = na, size = size.normal, color = color.new(color.white, 90))
lbls = label.new(x = bar_index, y = na, size = size.normal, color = color.new(color.white, 90))

bpic = "◀ "
spic = "◀ "
npic = "."

if sell and buy[1]
    label.set_text(lbls, bpic)
    label.set_y(lbls, sell_level)
    label.set_yloc(lbls, yloc.price)
    label.set_style(lbls, label.style_label_left)
else if buy and sell[1]
    label.set_text(lblb, spic)
    label.set_y(lblb, buy_level)
    label.set_yloc(lblb, yloc.price)
    label.set_style(lblb, label.style_label_left)
else
    lbln = label.new(x = bar_index, y = na, yloc = yloc.price, size = size.tiny, color = color.new(color.green, 90), style = label.style_none)
    
// Buy and Sell text values ----------------------------------------------------

bval = "Sell"
sval = "Buy"

if sell and buy[1]
    lblsv = label.new(x = bar_index, y = sell_level, size = size.normal, color = color.white, style = label.style_label_up)
    label.set_text(lblsv, bval)
    label.set_y(lblsv, sell_level)
    label.set_yloc(lblsv, yloc.belowbar)
else if buy and sell[1]
    lblbv = label.new(x = bar_index, y = buy_level, size = size.normal, color = color.white, style = label.style_label_down)
    label.set_text(lblbv, sval)
    label.set_y(lblbv, buy_level)
    label.set_yloc(lblbv, yloc.abovebar)
else
    lblnv = label.new(x = bar_index, y = na, yloc = yloc.price, size = size.tiny, color = color.new(color.red, 90), style = label.style_none)

// ALERTS =====================================================================

if buy and sell[1]
    alert('buy: ' + 'price=' + str.tostring(sell_level), alert.freq_once_per_bar)
else if sell and buy[1]
    alert('sell: ' + 'price=' + str.tostring(buy_level), alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are using `alert.freq_once_per_bar` in your `alert()` function. Change it to `alert.freq_all`.

Also, you have `barstate.isconfirmed` in your code. It will only be `true` if the script is calculating the last (closing) update of the current bar. Not sure if that's what you really want in this case.

Comment: Thank you. Good pointers. For the alerts I just changed the IF statements (took the second "and" part out) and that seems to work.
The barstate point:  well, I have read thru the manual a zillion times and seem to still miss somethings LOL.  Is there another way to ONLY look at the previous (not realtime) bars without using the barstatus functions?

Comment: Well, then just use `[]` without the `barstate` variables.

Comment: Also, if my answer solved your issue, please consider accepting it so we would know that this question has a valid answer.

Comment: Thank you.  It helped me to understand this part of pine-script more.  Much appreciated :-)